# MySQL dynamically selecting fields within join with where clause?

Tags: php, mysql

so I'm having trouble selecting a field only if another fields value is not equal to 0.

So, here's what's going on.

I have 3 tables, they are - `users`, `schools`, `campuses`

And basically, I need to select a single users data from these 3 tables. I'd like to only select the campus_name field from campuses if the users.campus_id field is not 0.

So, something pseudo coded like this might give you a better idea..

The query is being passed in a `$id` variable, that has some user's id.

```
SELECT users.*, schools.*, (if(users.campus_id != 0) then campuses.campus_name) 
FROM users, schools, campuses 
WHERE users.id = '$id' (if(users.campus_id != 0) then AND campuses.id = users.campus_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM schools, 
    users LEFT OUTER JOIN campuses 
        ON users.campus_id != 0 
        AND users.campus_id = campuses.id
WHERE users.school_id = schools.id
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are joining three tables together, you always expect a user to have a school, but they may not have a campus, and if this is the case, obviously nothing should be displayed.

The best you can do is acheive this with a **[LEFT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)** on campuses.

An example based on your pseudo code below:

```
SELECT u.*, s.*, c.campus_name
FROM users u
INNER JOIN schools s ON u.school_id = s.school_id
LEFT JOIN campuses c ON u.campus_id = c.campus_id
WHERE u.user_id = $userId
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want ALL the information displayed, but to display campus name ONLY if it exists? If so, I believe the following statement should do the trick:

```
SELECT `u`.* `s`.* if(`c`.`campus_name` != 0, `c`.`campus_name`, "") as `campus`
FROM `users` as `u`
INNER JOIN `schools` as `s` ON `u`.`school_id` = `s`.`school_id`
LEFT JOIN `campuses` as `c` ON `u`.`campus_id` = `c`.`campus_id`
WHERE `u`.`user_id` = $user_id;
```

Untested, written from the top of my head, could be errors in there